# Tkinter кнопка не реагирует на sticky="e"

Tags: python, tkinter

хочу что бы кнопки очистить и отправить находились в правом углу, поменять колонки у button1.grid(row=0, column=0) не помогло, tk.LEFT тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import tkinter as tk
 
window = tk.Tk()
row_list = [
    'Имя:','Фамилия:',
    'Адрес 1:', 'Адрес 2:',
    'Город', 'Регион:',
    'Почтовый индекс:',
    "Страна"]
            
frame1 = tk.Frame(master=window) 
for i in range(len(row_list)):
    frame1 = tk.Frame(master=window)        
    frame1.grid(row=i, column=0)
    
    frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window)        
    frame2.grid(row=i, column=1)
    
    label = tk.Label(master=frame1, text=row_list[i])
    entry = tk.Entry(master=frame2, width=40)
    
    
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    
frame3 = tk.Frame(master=window)        
button1 = tk.Button(master=frame3, width=12, text='Отправить')
button2 = tk.Button(master=frame3, width=12, text='Очистить')
frame3.grid(row=len(row_list), column=2)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sticky="e"` при размещении виджетов (кнопок) влияет на расположение этих виджетов внутри контейнера, где они находятся (`frame3`), но не влияет на то, как этот контейнер будет расположен внутри родительского контейнера (`window`) - по факту `frame3` просто центрируется в своей строке и колонке сетки. Нужно просто добавить `sticky="e"` при размещении `frame3`:

```
frame3.grid(row=len(row_list), column=1, sticky="e")
```

а для кнопок можно убрать.

Кстати, не понятно зачем для каждой метки и поля ввода создавать отдельный фрейм, можно было просто их все в одном фрейме разместить (плюс тогда можно использовать `pack` для размещения фреймов, т.к. `grid` для размещения двух фреймов в окне будет излишним):

```
frame1 = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame1.pack()

for i in range(len(row_list)):
    label = tk.Label(master=frame1, text=row_list[i])
    label.grid(row=i, column=0)
    entry = tk.Entry(master=frame1, width=40)
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
    
frame3 = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

button1 = tk.Button(master=frame3, width=12, text='Отправить')
button2 = tk.Button(master=frame3, width=12, text='Очистить')
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Или:
# button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
# button2.pack()
```

Скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо помогло)